# std::erase crash when count duplicate char in a loop?

Tags: c++, string

Segmentation fault is throw in the below code.

Counting total no of duplicate char As examples

**input**:

```
helloWorld
```

**output**:

```
l = 3
o = 2
```

steps

1. Loop input string
2. search for each char
3. count on found
4. del the counted char

Below is my code

```
#include<iostream>

#include<string>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
        std::string str;
        std::cin>>str;
        int cout = 0;
        std::string::iterator it1,it2;
        for(it1 = str.begin() ; it1!=str.end(); ++it1)
        {

                for(it2 = str.begin() ; it2!=str.end(); ++it2)
                {
                        if(*it1==*it2)
                        {
                                ++cout;
                                continue ;
                        }
                }
                if(cout >1)
                {
                        std::cout<<*it1<<"="<<cout<<"\n";
                        if(!str.empty() && str.find(*it1))
                          str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), *it1), str.end()); // remove char once count done
                }
                        cout=0;
        }
}
```

Comment: Using `cout` as a variable name will bite you hard, one day.

Comment: @Bathsheba existence of this code is one of the reasons why `using namespace std;` sucks.

Comment: @Bathsheba -- there's nothing wrong with using the name `cout` that way; that's what namespaces are for. It's only when someone blows away the standard namespace with the `using namespace std;` abomination that problems arise, and the solution to that is simple and obvious: don't do that.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Let's agree to do neither ;-) If I see `cout` then my mind says "console output", and does so more strongly at 3am when I'm debugging something in production.

Comment: @Bathsheba not really, unless someone is hardwired into `using namespace std`, and that might be a great way to unwire. However, having it like that reduces program readability greatly, so despite what I've just said, I would not advocate for actually having this variable.

Comment: This is an O^2 complexity solution for O(N) problem. It would do you good to think harder on how to do this in a better way.

Comment: @Bathsheba -- yes, it's a bad name, because it has implications that it doesn't satisfy. It should, of course, be `count`. I blame auto-correct. <g>

Comment: @Bathsheba sorry for typos I will take care for it and thanks lot for all the above comment will work on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your iterators `it1` and `it2` are being *invalidated* when you adjust the string `str`.

Don't do it like that. Use indexes into the `std::string` (of `std::size_t` types) instead.

(I'd solve this using an container `foo` say of `int` of size `CHAR_MAX - CHAR_MIN + 1`, initialised to zero, which is such that `foo[i]` is the number of times character `i` occurs. This can be populated in O(N), and the output stage is particularly trivial: see [Can the Duplicate Characters in a string be Identified and Quantified in O(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48064179/can-the-duplicate-characters-in-a-string-be-identified-and-quantified-in-on/48064566))

Comment: Better yet, redo the whole algo in a less terrible way.

Answer (score 0):

Use [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)'s built in functionality. By using [`sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) and [`adjacent_find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) to do this in *O(n log n)* time:

```
sort(begin(str), end(str));

for(auto start = adjacent_find(cbegin(str), cend(str)), finish = upper_bound(start, cend(str), *start); start != cend(str); start = adjacent_find(finish, cend(str)), finish = upper_bound(start, cend(str), *start)) {
   cout << *start << " = " << distance(start, finish) << endl;
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/qLmtzb)

Comment: Although I'd prefer O(N) with some storage overhead.

Comment: @Bathsheba I'll bite, you care to specify how you'd accomplish that?

Comment: I set out a possible approach in my answer, although getting it fully portable might be a pain.

Comment: This achieves the stated purpose but sorting will in general mean the character counts aren't output in the same order as they appear in the string.

Comment: @Bathsheba I could see perhaps using a radix sort or similar, which would give you *O(256)* (or whatever the number of potential characters there are is.) But it's input dependent on whether that will be better than *O(n log n)*.

Comment: @Bathsheba Actually let's just open a new question her: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48064179/2642059

Comment: @JonathanMee: Nice plug for about-to-be-upvoted question.

Comment: @Bathsheba To be fair, I thought the solution was more complex than `int storage[numeric_limits<char>::max - numeric_limits<char>::min + 1]`

Comment: @Persixty So the best solution for this is the linked question. If order of occurrence mattered you could use that solution and do: `for(const auto i : str) { if(storage[i - numeric_limits<char>::min] > 1) { cout << i << " = " << storage[i - numeric_limits<char>::min] << endl; storage[i - numeric_limits<char>::min] = 0; } }`